# the scene which containing a table view in java fx is not opening from the button provided in another scene

Tags: java, javafx, mapping, scenebuilder

I am trying to build a small java desktop application using JavaFX  to enter student details. On the opening scene I have provided buttons to switch into different scenes. I can access the other scenes but the scene with a TableView which contains all the student details from the database is not opening.

Here's my full error message;

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/H:/Java/Educational%20Centre/target/classes/com/example/educationalcentre/Table.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1024)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:759)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at com.example.educationalcentre/com.example.educationalcentre.SceneController.switchToTable(SceneController.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1853)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8944)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3980)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2704)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1022)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/collections/MappingChange$Map
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.<init>(TableView.java:2249)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableView.<init>(TableView.java:669)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableView.<init>(TableView.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange$Map
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 67 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1858)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8944)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3980)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2704)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1853)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/H:/Java/Educational%20Centre/target/classes/com/example/educationalcentre/Table.fxml:10

    at com.example.educationalcentre/com.example.educationalcentre.SceneController.switchToTable(SceneController.java:67)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/H:/Java/Educational%20Centre/target/classes/com/example/educationalcentre/Table.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1024)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:759)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at com.example.educationalcentre/com.example.educationalcentre.SceneController.switchToTable(SceneController.java:64)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1022)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/collections/MappingChange$Map
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.<init>(TableView.java:2249)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableView.<init>(TableView.java:669)
    at javafx.controls@20.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableView.<init>(TableView.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange$Map
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 67 more
```

**Here's the Table.fxml code;**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2- 
    ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            
    fx:controller="com.example.educationalcentre.TableController">
    <TableView fx:id="tblStudent" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="321.0" 
    prefWidth="600.0">
      <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="75.0" text="StudentID"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="fname" prefWidth="75.0" text="First 
      Name"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="lname" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last 
      Name"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="gender" prefWidth="75.0" 
     text="Gender"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="email" prefWidth="75.0" text="Email"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="dob" prefWidth="75.0" text="BirthDay"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="cstatus" prefWidth="75.0" text="Civil 
      Status"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="address" prefWidth="75.0" text="Address"/>
      </columns>
    </TableView>
    <Label layoutX="9.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="339.0" text="Student List">
        <font>
          <Font size="35.0"/>
        </font>
    </Label>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Here's my controller class for the scene containing table view**

```
    package com.example.educationalcentre;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TableController implements Initializable {
    StudentService studentService;
    @FXML
    private TableView <Student> tblStudent;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn <Student, Integer>  id;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn <Student,String> fname;

    @FXML private  TableColumn <Student,String> lname;
    @FXML private TableColumn <Student,String> gender;
    @FXML private TableColumn <Student,String> email;
    @FXML private TableColumn <Student, Date> dob;
    @FXML private TableColumn <Student,String> cstatus;
    @FXML private TableColumn <Student, String> address;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        try {
            loadStudent();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
    @FXML
        private void loadStudent() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        studentService = new StudentService();
        ObservableList<Student> students;
        students = FXCollections.observableArrayList(studentService.getStudentList());
      id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Integer>("studentID"));
      fname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("firstName"));

        lname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("lastName"));
        address.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("address"));
        email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("email"));
        cstatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("civilStatus"));
        gender.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("gender"));
        dob.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Date>("DOB"));

        tblStudent.setItems(students);
```

**Here's the method in my controller class for the first window of my program which contains the button to open the scene with the controller class**

```
@FXML
public void switchToTable(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
FXMLLoader(RegistryApplication.class.getResource("Table.fxml"));
     stage = (Stage) 
((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    try {
        scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows that you are mixing libraries from JavaFX 20.0.1 and libraries from JavaFX 21.0.1.  I’m not sure how that happened, but I suggest doing a clean build—meaning, delete all .jar files and executables that you have built, and build them from scratch.  Also, you should edit your question and show us the contents of your Table.fxml file.

Comment: I'll try. I have edited the question

Comment: The class not found `com/sun/javafx/collections/MappingChange$Map`was [recently removed from JavaFX](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/972/files#diff-0c5dea49a4ace580e54a17cded776439261e359b2d421b5d0d845d04ab85237dL34).  Probably your mixed JavaFX versions used is the cause of the issue.  All your JavaFX libraries should be the same version (and best to use latest stable as per VGR - 21.0.1 at the moment).  Because the problem is likely environmental for you, it is unlikely somebody else will be able to replicate it.

Comment: @VGR I rebuilt it from scratch and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for your insights. I rebuilt the program and the dependencies were now different. As you said it was environmental i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the dependencies (environmental). I have no idea what caused for that. After I rebuilt the program from scratch it worked fine without any change in the code. The dependencies mentioned in the xml have changed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

From the stack trace is hard to figure out what went wrong. I suggest adding some code.

Now from my experience this could be that you didn't create `Controller` class and added it to XML file. Please provide your XML so I could help you more

Comment: I have edited my question plz have a look